# remove characters from URL redirect in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, regex

I'm trying to remove certain characters from old URLs upon redirecting to a new URL.

The characters are:

! * _

I have an old website:

> old.com/forums

and a new website:

> new.com/community

I'd like to redirect many URLs, some which look like this:

> old.com/forums/thread/68.baking!muffins!_yummy*
>
> old.com/forums/thread/419.hellothere

I want them to look like this:

> new.com/community/thread/68.bakingmuffinsyummy
>
> new.com/community/thread/419.hellothere

Here's my failed attempt at a directive to remove the ! character:

```
rewrite ^/forums(.*)[!](.*)$   new.com/community$1$2 permanent;
```

It only removes the last !, and doesn't work if there isn't a ! present. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible with regex?

Comment: Show how new url should looks like

Comment: You can rewrite the characters recursively and then redirect the final result. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/888059/finish-processing-rewrite-directives-in-location-and-return-301/888098#888098)

Comment: thanks @RichardSmith here's what I came up with:

`location /forums/ {
rewrite ^(.*)\!(.*)$ $1$2 last;
rewrite ^(.*)\*(.*)$ $1$2 last;
rewrite ^(.*)\_(.*)$ $1$2 last;
rewrite ^/forums(.*)$ community$1 permanent;
}`

I'm sure it could be cleaner, but it's working!

Comment: You could probably combine the first three regular expressions into `^(.*)[!*_](.*)$`